# HTTPS handshake failure on IoT device

Tags: javascript, api, https, iot, buildroot

I am running buildroot and iotjs on an iot device and I'm trying to make a post request to login and get an auth token. But I'm unable to call the API at all because I run into an error that says

"API Failed, problem with request: handshake failed: domian"

The same API works given I use the http version. The server I'm trying to call is hosted on an AWS EC2 instance behind cloudflare.

The code (not exactly the same but similar) used to call the API:

```
var https = require('https');

var options = {
  host: 'www.google.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/upload',
  method: 'POST'
};

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

// write data to request body
req.write('data\n');
req.write('data\n');
req.end();
```

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: is the IOT device able to make https requests?

Comment: How do you find out if it can?

Comment: by knowing what the device is and any limitations it may have - what is the iot device?

Comment: Processor : ARMv7 Processor rev 5 (v7l)
BogoMIPS : 9600.00
Features : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp thumbee neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part : 0xc07
CPU revision : 5

Hardware : sun8i
Revision : 0000
Serial  : 94107891491c2c1d0d10

Comment: This is all the info I have

Comment: so, it's a raspberry pi? or similar?

Comment: I'm guessing something similar, so what do you think?

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: Can anyone help?